# How can I create a dictionary within a function?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary within my function, but I cannot. The only possible solution I have found is to create the name of the dictionary outside the function and before calling it.

```
argentina = {}
def get_dic(file,phone):
    for line in file.readlines():
        if (line[0] == '#'):
            names = line.rstrip().strip()
            phone[names] = ''
        else:
            phone[names] = phone[names] + line.rstrip().strip()

get_dic(open(sys.argv[1],'r'), argentina)
```

`get_dic(open(sys.argv[1],'r'), argentina)` will open a dictionary called 'argentina', but I wont need to create `argentina = {}` in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `return`ing the dictionary from the function?

Comment: Also, `names` is undefined in `else` (or rather, the value from the last iteration -- or is this intentional?) and `rstrip().strip()` is redundant.

Comment: thanks! . why rstrip().strip() is redundant?

Comment: It's redundant because it first strips whitespace from the right side of the string and then from both sides.

Answer (score 6):

Just create the dict inside and return it from the function:

```py
def get_dic(file):
    phone = {}
    names = None
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[0] == '#':
            names = line.strip()
            phone[names] = ""
        else:
            phone[names] += line.strip()
    return phone

argentina = get_dic(open(sys.argv[1],'r'))
```

Comment: On closer inspection, setting `names` only in `if` might be intentional, in order to accumulate lines in blocks starting at lines with `#`...